# SFML/C++ Simulating user input

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to write some unit test methods. I want to test method which checks if key is pressed or released. And here is my question:

> Is it possible in SFML with C++ to simulate random key press on keyboard?

Or I will just have to trust myself that this works?

Comment: May I atleast know what do I get down voted for?

Comment: Someone voted because they considered the question too broad but this is not really the case here, you're asking about a specific library.

Comment: As for your question, http://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=14611.0 answers part of it (not possible to simulate globally)

Comment: @coyotte508 Thanks for answer, so I will have to look for some external tools to deal with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The internals of `sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed` would make simulation difficult, but if you are looking to simulate KeyPressed or KeyReleased *events* I'm pretty sure the following should work:

```
const sf::Event simulateKeypress(sf::Keyboard::Key key, bool alt, bool control, bool shift, bool system)
{
    sf::Event::KeyEvent data;
    data.code = key;
    data.alt = alt;
    data.control = control;
    data.shift = shift;
    data.system = system;

    sf::Event event;
    event.type = sf::Event::KeyPressed;
    event.key = data;
    return event;
}

//your handler here
handleEvent(simulateKeypress(sf::Keyboard::Key::A, false, false, false, false));
```

I'm unable to test this at the moment... If it works, then you should be able to make similar functions for other events.

Comment: I think you just solved my problem :D Thank you, really helpful :)

Comment: @JakubStasiak Glad to hear it! I take it the code is correct? Best of luck with your program.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can if you use a key manager of your own.
An example in C with SDL (but its exactly the same in C++ with SFML, just few name to change) :

```
    typedef struct
    {
        char key[SDLK_LAST];
        int mousex,mousey;
        int mousexrel,mouseyrel;
        char mousebuttons[8];
            char quit;
    } Input;


 void UpdateEvents(Input* in)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    while(SDL_PollEvent(&event))
    {
        switch (event.type)
        {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            in->key[event.key.keysym.sym]=1;
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            in->key[event.key.keysym.sym]=0;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEMOTION:
            in->mousex=event.motion.x;
            in->mousey=event.motion.y;
            in->mousexrel=event.motion.xrel;
            in->mouseyrel=event.motion.yrel;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            in->mousebuttons[event.button.button]=1;
            break;
        case SDL_MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            in->mousebuttons[event.button.button]=0;
            break;
        case SDL_QUIT:
            in->quit = 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    Input in;

    memset(&in,0,sizeof(in));
    while(!in.key[SDLK_ESCAPE] && !in.quit)
    {
        UpdateEvents(&in);
        if (in.mousebuttons[SDL_BUTTON_LEFT])
        {
            in.mousebuttons[SDL_BUTTON_LEFT] = 0;

        }       

        if (in.key[SDLK_UP] && in.key[SDLK_LEFT])
                {

                }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Edit : Found a key manager for C++ SFML : https://github.com/dabbertorres/SwiftInputManager

Can't give you my own code cause the code is not in english